# Radio buttons using d3 not horizontally aligned

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use the following code for radio buttons in my d3 code:

```
var shapeData = ["Arrow", "Cross", "Hexagon", "Star", "Triangle"], 
    j = 3;  // Choose the star as default

// Create the shape selectors
var form = d3.select("body").append("form");

labels = form.selectAll("label")
    .data(shapeData)
    .enter()
    .append("label")
    .text(function(d) {return d;})
    .append("input")
    .attr({
        type: "radio",
        class: "shape",
        name: "mode",
        value: function(d, i) {return i;}
    })
    .attr(function(d, i) {return i==j?"selected":null;});
```

However, the radio buttons are getting vertically aligned. i.e., on top of one another. Please let me  know what I am missing to get them horizontally aligned.

Comment: Without any styling your code seems to be working just fine:http://jsfiddle.net/blakedietz/tNG8E/. Do you want the radio buttons to be stacked or to be in-line?

Comment: Yes code works perfectly in the fiddle. However, I am getting a different output i.e. each radio box in a different line. I would like to hava a output similar to the fiddle.

Comment: what does your shape class look like?